# Fishing spots in greater Atlanta area?

Tags: fishing

An avid novice angler with some experience with bass fishing, I recently moved to northern Atlanta. I love the cultural dynamics here in Atlanta, but haven't had a chance to meet other anglers. I would be grateful for some information on good spots for bank fishing (any kind of fish) north of Atlanta.

Comment: I love to fish small retention ponds and such with ultra light tackle... hop onto Google Maps, zoom in and look for blue :)

Comment: @ivanivan Lol. Have been doing that for a while. The problem is bank access is not marked on Google Maps or even known to outsiders. Last time I spent 20 minutes trying to find access to a lake

Answer (score 2):

Bull Sluice Lake is a great place. There is bank access as well as a dock.